# Issue with setting 40th bit of long variable

Tags: java

I'm playing around with bit manipulation in Java and I'm having a problem setting the 40th bit of a `Long` variable. When I do that, it just circles back to the 8th bit. So, that to me means that it is 32bit (instead of 64). However, my understanding is that `Long`/`long` is 2^64 in Java. I'm probably missing something here.

Here's the test code I've been toying around with in 
code.sololearn.com

```
   Long k = 256L; 
   Long x = Long.valueOf((1 << 40));

   System.out.println(x);
```

The above code returns 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 << 40` is an int-expression (and will effectively lead to `1 << (40 % 32) = 1 << 8`, which evaluates to `256`). Try using `1L << 40`.

Here is an [<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/o4dabC).